# Open different views in ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I have such an application layout:
https://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/appMenu.png

MainViewControler - View from the side menu (view with icons on the left + view from containerview for displaying subsequent views).

ConceptViewController - view with different pictures (picture buttons).

ConceptGalleryViewController - here I will want to display the gallery.
The gallery will be displayed in the same containerView in MainViewControler as the ConceptViewController is displayed.

The view in the ContainerView in the MainViewControler of the ConceptViewController view is done with the following code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var systemContainerView: UIView!

@IBAction func homeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        showSubViewInContainerView(view: "HomeView")
    }


    func showSubViewInContainerView(view: String){
        let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: view)
        addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        systemContainerView.addSubview(controller.view)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.trailingAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.topAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: systemContainerView.bottomAnchor)
            ])

        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

It works great.

When I click on the selected icon in ConceptViewController, I open the ConceptGalleryViewController view with the following code:

```
var idGallery = 0

    @IBAction func shareTheFunBtnChecked(_ sender: Any) {
        idGallery = 1
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toConceptGalleryView", sender: self)
    }
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "toConceptGalleryView" {
            let target = segue.destination as! ConceptGalleryViewController
            target.idGallery = idGallery
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, it does not work correctly.
The side menu disappears and I have a new board for the entire screen.

How can I change this so that ConceptGalleryViewController can be seen in ContainerView?

**UPDATE**

This code not working:

```
@IBAction func shareTheFunBtnChecked(_ sender: Any) {
        idGallery = 1
        showSubViewInContainerView(view: "ConceptGalleryView")
    }

func showSubViewInContainerView(view: String){
        let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: view)
        addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainView") as! MainViewControler
        viewController.systemContainerView.addSubview(controller.view)


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.systemContainerView.leadingAnchor),
            controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.systemContainerView.trailingAnchor),
            controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.systemContainerView.topAnchor),
            controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.systemContainerView.bottomAnchor)
            ])

        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

I have error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in code:

```
viewController.systemContainerView.addSubview(controller.view)
```

**UPDATE 2**

If I'm trying this code:

```
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: view)
        addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainView") as! MainViewControler
        viewController.systemContainerView?.addSubview(controller.view)

        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

The ConceptGalleryViewController view does not show up. The application does nothing

Comment: Try Checking working code https://github.com/RockinGarg/ContainerView-TabBar.git , One containerView, Three Buttons and two Different ViewController as Subview and one TabBar as Subview in ContainerView

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for me. I added the answer in the question - section UPDATE)...

Answer (score 0):

Please find the sample app i have created container view in storyboard and adding child view programatically. It works fine for me.

Source code is uploaded in the below dropbox link.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cz8abhltefbtqpb/ContainerDemo.zip?dl=0